# How to write a value object in XAML using markup extension?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to replace

```
<Button Text="Foo" Command="{Binding Foo}">
    <Button.CommandParameter>
        <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
    </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>
```

with something like

```
<Button ... CommandParameter="{???}"/>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can write a markup extension by deriving from the MarkupExtension class and implementing the ProvideValue method:

```
public class BooleanValueExtension : MarkupExtension
{
  private readonly bool _value;

  public BooleanValueExtension(bool value)
  {
    _value = value;
  }

  public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
  {
    return _value;
  }
}
```

You can then use this using the brace syntax:

```
<Button CommandParameter="{local:BooleanValue True}" />
```